# SERP Meta Title Issues

Tags: schema.org, title

I have this site I am working on, its a travel site. Today I saw a very unusual result in Google. For query - "flight from x to y" I am seeing my client site title as - "to y- flight from x to y".

I am not sure why this is happening, why google is showing "to y". Only explanation I have right now is text in schema markup, last element is used is "to y" but again google never grabs content from markup. And I could not find "to y" being used as it is anywhere on the page.

Page does have content targeted towards "flight from x to y" and used many time but not as "to y".

Comment: This comes from the answer engine. It is trying to answer a question.